# How can I empty a database when it reaches 100 records/rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I automatically empty a MySQL database when it reaches a 100 records/rows?
The database gets bigger really quick and I can't empty it all of the time because of school (I can't use my laptop there).
When there is a lot of records in the table, the action of the form will take longer to finish that's why I want the records to be deleted when reached 100 records.
I am new to the MySQL things & I would really appropriate an answer that will solve my problem :)

The database name is: db181894_names

The table is: Names

MySQL code: jsfiddle.net/LFNHr/

Comment: Leave the records there and work on making the form processing run faster.  100 records is tiny.

Comment: mysql can handle millions of rows efficiently. If you are experiencing lag on just 100, perhaps you should post your query for review. You may be doing something that causes the choke (like nested in selects, etc) - or the table is not set up correctly

Comment: The web hosting I am using doesn't allow more than a 100 records to be processed in the <form>. It shows "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR" If the table has more than 100 records (when the form is submitted).
That's why I am trying to make the limit of the records 100 and the 100 will be deleted automatically..

Comment: If your business (case) lets you to empty the database, why are you persisting data at first place? Just ignore it! And if you want to store only 100 records, store the records in a `Map` in memory, or use a memory only database.

Comment: @Amir Pashazadeh but the users will need to get information from the database using a <form>. But it will say "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR" if the database has more than 100 records when the user(s) submitted the <form>. So I can't ignore it because it's showing an error that I need to fix :) 
Thanks

Comment: @user3213765 so I believe there must be some other problem with your application/database! 100 records is nothing for any major DBMS including MySQL.

Comment: @Amir Pashazadeh Yes, there is some kind of a problem and it's still not fixed for now :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a restriction on adding a new record to a table.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM table1;
  IF @cnt >= 100 THEN
    TRUNCATE TABLE  table1;
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note, that COUNT operation may be slow on big InnoDb tables.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to delete records after 100 would be to have an int ++ each time one is added, or a list that keeps track of the Primary Keys as they are added.

That being said, like most of the other people have stated, 100 records is a grain of sand in the desert.  If I had to make a guess, the problem most likely lies with your query, or within the code that is making the query.

If you are doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM things
foreach (item in items){
  SELECT * FROM things // again
}
```

this would cause an issue.  Could you post your code and a mock version of one of your records?

EDIT:

Yes, from the looks of your code you are doing a select, and then for each item returned from the query it does another query to the API (which is actually a second query ... just not locally).

If you did a query against your Likers table, and built another table called API_Results and populated as much of the data with information you already pulled from facebook and use API for what you haven't seen yet ... it will most likely go a lot faster.

So for example, you build a second table in your db w/ all the fields you are collecting from the API and then a method for requesting said data from your local db if_exists ... and if not it pulls it from API to populate your local copy as well as the page you are building.

RE-EDIT:

```
tuples1 = SELECT * FROM Likers

foreach( item in tuples1):
  tuples2 = SELECT * from API_Results WHERE primarykey_in_tuples1 == field_in_API_Results
  if(tuples2 == NOTHING):
    // Grab API From FaceBOok
    // INSERT API_Results (value, names, in, table) VALUES (some, values, from, facebook)
    // Generate Page from Values
  else:
    // Generate Page from tuples2
```

tell me if this makes sense - Caffeine

Comment: Hey @CaffeineAddiction, what is the code for that? you said I should collect fields from the API to make the process faster :)
Can you please help me out with what you just said? I am really new to all of the MySQL codes
Thanks

Comment: @user3213765 give me a min, I will write some psudocode

Comment: Where do I put that code? Do I have to removed the old one and put this one or just keep the old one and add this one to the bottom of the php code? :) 
Thanks

Comment: @user3213765 well, like I said, it is psudocode ... it wont work if you just copy and paste.  But it does give you the Logic behind what does need to be written.  IMO, you should have a method named getAPIDATA() and then check your db, and then check facebook API if your DB is empty.

Comment: I guess I will just ask the web hosting  to make the request process to get information from more than 100 records from the table because I don't think it's possible to empty the table when it reaches amount of records :)
Thanks

Comment: Well, if you just want to limit the number of returns from your Select use change your statement to `SELECT * FROM Likers LIMIT 10`

Comment: Thank you!!! @CaffeineAddiction
Now I am using the LIMIT 100 and the error is not showing anymore! :)
Thanks man, I appreciate it.